# MS Word: Creating shortcut or toolbar button for the "Paste Special..Unformatted Text" option

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have been playing with this for a while, but the closest I have gotten is a button that opens the `Paste Special` dialog box and requires another couple of mouse clicks to paste the contents of the clipboard as unformatted text.

So often I am doing a `copy-paste` from a web site into a document where I don't want the additional baggage of the HTML formatting, it would be nice to be able to do this with a shortcut key or a toolbar button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the button call the macro:

```
public sub PasteSpecialUnformatted()
  selection.pastespecial datatype:=wdpastetext
end sub
```

Comment: He's asking for help with MS Word he's not going to go through the effort of writing VB script.

Comment: That's what you think. I have been using the macro since it was posted!

I admit I was hoping for a non-macro solution, but this works just fine. Not sure why you think I wouldn't go through the effort of writing a VB script considering I am a programmer by trade.

Comment: Programmer by trade here, but not one who's done VB scripting before. I'd like to use this PasteSpecialUnformatted macro. Where do I enter it?

Comment: You press Alt+F11 in your Office app to open the IDE, then press Ctrl+R to activate the project tree, then right-click it to insert a module, then paste this code into it.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) lightweight utility application by Steve Miller for this.

PureText runs in your system tray and listens on a global hotkey (which you can define -- I use Win+V) to perform a "paste text sans formatting" -- essentially the same operation as opening up an instance of notepad.exe, pasting into that, re-copying the resultant plain text, and then pasting into the actual target application.

The advantage of this approach is that you'll be able to perform a "paste text sans formatting" in any of your applications, not just in Word.

I first installed PureText a couple of years ago and have been using it heavily ever since; it has become a "must-have" utility application for me.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I use [FingerTips](http://www.getfingertips.com/) for this. By default it will make CTRL+W -> Paste Special. Furthermore it supports macro text and a lot of useful start-programs-quick things and some Microsoft Outlook tricks to support Getting Things Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Quick Access Panel in MS Word 2007 and later versions.

It is very simple to add  [Shortcut Buttons in MS Office](http://dadecoder.blogspot.in/2013/02/add-shortcut-buttons-in-ms-word-2007.html)

And saves a lot of time for regular users.